# passport-oauth2 generated access token not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, zooming

I am using Node.Js, Express, passport, and passport-oauth2 to develop a few simple API endpoints.

I am able to generate a token using passport-oauth2 and I am using it to set the header of a redirect.

```
    app.get('/auth/example',passport.authenticate('oauth2'), 
    (req, res) => {res.send("Hello example.")}
    );

app.get('/auth/example/redirect', (req, res) => {
  console.log("accessToken is " + req.query.code) ; 
  res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + req.query.code);
  res.redirect(301, 'https://somepublicAPIendpoint');   
});
```

It is getting redirected to the http://somepublicAPIendpoint; but I get an error stating that it is an `Invalid access token`.

I have tried invoking this https://somepublicAPIendpoint  through postman in two ways.

1. Using the access token that can be generated from Postman itself. - works as expected. Token code is > 200 chars.
2. Using the access token that passport-oauth2 has generated. - `Invalid access token`. The token code is ~50 chars.

I understand that the passport-oauth2 token generation isn't working as expected. This is the strategy that I have used.

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://api.zoom.us/oauth/token',
    clientID: 'clientId',
    clientSecret: 'secretId',
    callbackURL: "http://myapp/auth/example/redirect"
  }, 
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {console.log("callback function invoked.") ;}
));
```

How do I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scopes that you are requesting access to. Example

passport.authenticate('oauth2', {scope: ['user_profile', 'user:read', 'user:read:admin']})